# Reshaping from long to wide for characters instead of values and manipulation in R

Tags: r, duplicates, reshape

I have a subdata as below. I would like to do some manipulations in 3 steps:

1. reshape it to long format so that for each "id" I see the "m" columns.
2. for each id only keeping one of the repetitions, e.g id 101 has two "15 ag", I would like to keep only one. Only one even I see many repetitions.
3. assign the values in column "m" to some scores, as: "15 ag" assign to 0, "12 cer" assign to 1,"18 di" assign to 6,"11 dem" assign to 2,"25 dia" assign to 0.
4. then I sum all the scores up in a new column called "sum".
   In the end, I will have for each id the "sum".

Any help for this is appreciated.

```
d <- structure(list(id = c(101, 101, 101, 101, 102, 102, 102, 103, 
                           103, 103, 103, 104), m = c("15 ag", "15 ag", NA, "12 cer", NA, 
                          "18 di", "12 cer", "11 dem", "11 dem", NA, "12 cer", "25 dia"
                           )), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"),row.names =c(NA,-12L))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse)

d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(m = case_when(
    m %in% c("15 ag", "25 dia") ~ 0,
    m == "12 cer" ~ 1,
    m == "18 di" ~ 6,
    m == "11 dem" ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  )) %>% 
  summarise(sum = sum(m))

# A tibble: 4 × 2
     id   sum
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   101     1
2   102     7
3   103     3
4   104     0
```

New column without summarise

```
d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  distinct() %>%
  drop_na() %>%
  mutate(m = case_when(
    m %in% c("15 ag", "25 dia") ~ 0,
    m == "12 cer" ~ 1,
    m == "18 di" ~ 6,
    m == "11 dem" ~ 2,
    TRUE ~ NA_real_
  )) %>% 
  mutate(sum = sum(m))

# A tibble: 7 × 3
# Groups:   id [4]
     id     m   sum
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1   101     0     1
2   101     1     1
3   102     6     7
4   102     1     7
5   103     2     3
6   103     1     3
7   104     0     0
```